# MATLAB sort containers.Map(key, value) by key

Tags: matlab, sorting, dictionary, containers

I have a map `containers.Map(array1, array2)` that I would like to sort according to the *values in array1*. There is a fairly large amount of data contained in the arrays (~50,000 elements in each).

Is there a simple way to do this, perhaps using some built-in MATLAB feature?

Environment is MATLAB 2012. `array1` is a character array.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a `container.Map` is a dictionary or hash table implementation you cannot define some ordering of the elements within the data structure itself. However, by default MATLAB sorts `keys` and `values` (according to `keys`) when you query for them:

```
keySet =   {'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'};
valueSet = [327.2, 368.2, 197.6, 178.4];
mapObj = containers.Map(keySet,valueSet);

>> keys(mapObj)
ans = 
    'Apr'    'Feb'    'Jan'    'Mar'

>> values(mapObj)
ans = 
    [178.4000]    [368.2000]    [327.2000]    [197.6000]
```

Comment: if sorting by map's value, then any function exist ?

Comment: @minssi what does your question mean? I don't understand what your asking.

Comment: btw it sorts it in increasing order e.g. `{[0]}    {[1.0000e-07]}    {[1.0000e-06]}    {[1.0000e-05]}    {[1.0000e-04]}    {[1.0000e-03]}`.